# WPF Border Color Binding to parent Controls Tag

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem where I have to bind to Tag property. But don't know what will come here.

```
<Border x:Name="BorderStatus" CornerRadius="2" Tag="Transparent">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Tag, ????}" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Tag, ????}" Offset="0.47"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.77"/>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkRed" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

This is done cause there are triggers which will change the tag property.

We can bind with `ElementName` but is there any other way?

Comment: What's the scope of this Tag property? Is it the property of GradiendtStop's class?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir: I want to bind to Tag Property of Border Class.

Comment: Have you try this, like, `Color="{Binding ElementName=BorderStatus, Path=Tag}"`

Comment: For background, read about inheritance context in WPF: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickkramer/2006/08/17/whats-an-inheritance-context/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of accomplishing your goal I can think of are these:

I. Use `Binding.ElementName` property:

```
Color="{Binding Tag, ElementName=BorderStatus}"
```

II. Use `RelativeSource` in `FindAncestor` mode:

```
Color="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
```